# Pass viewport camera world space position to shader

Tags: materials, shaders

AFAIK, the [Camera Data](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/input/camera_data.html) node doesn't provide viewport camera's position, what alternatives do I have?

Comment: 'View'/'View Lock'/'Lock camera to view' ?

Comment: @lemon what I actually want is to use this position to write custom lighting, so I don't need to switch to active camera to see the shading result.